# How to install the package font awesome?

Tags: packages, installing

How to install the package font awesome in MiXTeX (Windows)?

Comment: Please review the answers to your other questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149828/how-to-make-dominoes-falling, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157199/where-can-i-find-on-off-symbol, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154634/how-to-draw-a-modulo-13-clock-like-diagram, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133332/to-draw-a-chessboard, for instance. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: http://docs.miktex.org/faq/packages.html

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36688/benedito?tab=questions&sort=newest) is a list of your questions. You can see which have answers but no accepted answer, and which have multiple answers. This should help you to identify the questions and answers @Jubobs is referring to.

Comment: @LaRoFaRi: It hasn't to be installed manually: it is part of the MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: @Bernard true. Just wanted to add some possibility in case my first link does not help. I retracted my close vote. But maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196555 would be a dupe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the fontawesome package is part of MiKTeX.