# Construct A Spiral-Like Layers of Arcs Using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, spiral

I want to use tikz to construct layers of arc folding all around a 12 integer-graded circle with each arc having a constant length of a quarter-of-a-circle and the first starting at 90 degrees, the consecutive arcs starting 30 degrees ahead of the previous until the 12th arc just like this:

[image: hand-drawn sketch]

I have tried to construct just the `12-integer-graded circle`

[image: as this]

in the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        %
        % Independent parameters
        \pgfmathsetmacro\dth{360/12}                            % angular increment
        \def\angleOffset{90}                                    % starting angle
        \def\dialR{1}                                           % dial radius
        \def\dialLabelOffset{-.1}                                % label radial offset
        %
        % Dependent parameters
        \pgfmathsetmacro\angleTip{-11.99*\dth+\angleOffset}      % tip angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\dialLabelR{\dialR+\dialLabelOffset}    % label radius
        %   
        % draw arc
        \draw[thick,-]
        (\angleOffset:\dialR) arc (\angleOffset:\angleTip:\dialR);
        %
        % write labels
        \foreach
        [
        var=\k,
        var=\dialLabel,
        evaluate=\k as \th using -\k*\dth+\angleOffset,
        ]
        in {0/12,1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4,5/5,6/6,7/7,8/8,9/9,10/10,11/11,12/12}%
        { 
            \draw (\th:\dialLabelR) node {\dialLabel};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I modified the above code from an answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154634/how-to-draw-a-modulo-13-clock-like-diagram)

**NOTE**

I need an easy-to-understand latex code for a layman like me to modify it for use. As I may want to remove an arc, rearrange them, or remove the graded circle, let each arc's code be independent of the other.

Comment: `\foreach[count=\i from 0] \j in {1, ..., 13} \draw (-\i*30+90:\dialR+\j*.2) arc[start angle=-\i*30+90, delta angle=-90, radius=\dialR+\j*.2];` could be a start. If you want to remove one without the others filling in the space you will need to write them out each for themselves or use the list for the distance to `\dialR`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
  \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
  
  % dial
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius=\dialR];

  % hour tips
  \foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
    \draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR)-- ++({hourstoangle(\num)}:-1mm);
  }
  
  % hour labels
  \foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
    \draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR-5mm) node{\num};
  }

  % arcs
  \foreach \num in {0,...,12}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}

    \draw
    % two tips
    ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
    ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
    % one arc
    ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
    arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt];
  }
  
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]