# Tikz: Modify Some Spiral-Like Layers of Arcs to Form Layers of A Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I edit the following code from the [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685539/construct-a-spiral-like-layers-of-arcs-using-tikz)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
        
        % dial
        %\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\dialR];
        
        % hour tips
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR)-- ++({hourstoangle(\num)}:-1mm);
        %}
        
        % hour labels
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR-5mm) node{\num};
        %}
        
        % arcs
        \foreach \num in {0,...,11}{%\foreach \num in {0,...,12}{ I only need 12 and not 13 arcs
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}
            
            \draw
            % two tips
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            % one arc
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt];
        }
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**WHAT I WANT**

1. I want to be able to label each arc as I have manually done in the image below.
2. I want to be able to move some arcs on the outer layer to the inner
   layers where spaces exist. For instance, move `B_4` and `B_7` to the
   same layer of `B_1` while. `B_5` and `B_8` are repositioned to the
   same layer of 'B_2' and `B_6` is repositioned to the same layer of
   `B_3`. The whole picture will then be a circle of 3 layers instead
   of a spiral.

as shown in the first image [image: below].

I want the arcs labelled to be embedded in the centre of each ack similar to the marked part of the [image: second image below].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT 3

The spiral version with labels on the curves, which you could have make by yourself, by following the same tip I already gave you. Anyway, here it is:

[image: version 4]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
        
        % dial
        %\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\dialR];
        
        % hour tips
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR)-- ++({hourstoangle(\num)}:-1mm);
        %}
        
        % hour labels
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR-5mm) node{\num};
        %}
        
        % arcs
        \foreach \num [count= \n from 1] in {0,...,11}{%\foreach \num in {0,...,12}{ I only need 12 and not 13 arcs
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}
            
            \draw
            % two tips
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            % one arc
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt] node[sloped,midway,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,allow upside down]{$B_{\n}$};
        }
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
        
        % dial
        %\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\dialR];
        
        % hour tips
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR)-- ++({hourstoangle(\num)}:-1mm);
        %}
        
        % hour labels
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR-5mm) node{\num};
        %}
        
        % arcs
        \foreach \num [count= \n from 1] in {0,...,11}{%\foreach \num in {0,...,12}{ I only need 12 and not 13 arcs
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}
            
            \draw
            % two tips
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            % one arc
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt] node[sloped,midway,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,allow upside down]{$B_{\n}$};
        }
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

### EDIT

And here the version with `allow upside down` if you want every nodes on the outer space of the circles.

[image: version 2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
        
        % dial
        %\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\dialR];
        
        % hour tips
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR)-- ++({hourstoangle(\num)}:-1mm);
        %}
        
        % hour labels
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR-5mm) node{\num};
        %}
        
        % arcs
        \foreach \num [count= \n from 1] in {0,...,11}{%\foreach \num in {0,...,12}{ I only need 12 and not 13 arcs
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}
            
            \draw
            % two tips
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            % one arc
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt] node[sloped,midway,above]{$B_{\n}$};
        }
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
        
        \newcommand{\drawcircle}[1]{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+#1 mm}
            
            \draw
            % two tips
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            % one arc
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt] node[sloped,midway,above,allow upside down]{$B_{\n}$};}
        % arcs
        \foreach \num [evaluate = \num as \n using int(\num+1)] in {0,3,6,9}{%
            \drawcircle{0}
        }
        \foreach \num [evaluate = \num as \n using int(\num+1)] in {1,4,7,10}{%
            \drawcircle{6}
        }
        \foreach \num [evaluate = \num as \n using int(\num+1)] in {2,5,8,11}{%
            \drawcircle{12}
        }
       
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{document}
```

### EDIT 2

By slightly changing the nodes parameters, you can have what you want:

`node[sloped,midway,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,allow upside down]` instead of `node[sloped,midway,above,allow upside down]`

[image: version 3]

On a side note, since you're on this website for a while now, you could have benefit from the many answers you got to learn a bit about Ti*k*Z. Maybe you should try sometimes ;)

Comment: Please help me address the following: (1) place arc labels in the centre of each arc. (2) Arc labels should be adhered to each arc, so that, if the arc is repositioned, its labels will follow.

Comment: Please check my `edit` to see the image illustration of my two requests above.

Comment: I want a label similar to your two outputs on the first `tikz` code in my recent edit. I am sorry, I have some complications with my edit.

Comment: Please run the `tikz` code on my recent edit, I need to label the `first` `tikz` code just the same way you have labelled the others.

Comment: It's done, but seriously, it was only a quick fix and you already had the tip to do it.

Comment: Please refresh and read my question stating from where I write **EDIT AGAIN** you will understand what I mean.