# Label the Tikz Arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, arc

I want your help to label the `tikz` in the below `code` just the way this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685675/tikz-modify-some-spiral-like-layers-of-arcs-to-form-layers-of-a-circle) is labelled.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius
        
        % dial
        %\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\dialR];
        
        %% hour tips
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR)-- ++({hourstoangle(\num)}:-1mm);
            %}
        
        %% hour labels
        %\foreach \num in {1,...,12}{
            %\draw ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dialR-5mm) node{\num};
            %}
        
        % arcs
        \foreach \num in {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}
            
            \draw
            % two tips
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt-1mm) -- ({hourstoangle(\num+3)}:\dist pt+1mm)
            % one arc
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt];
        }
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: A sample of what I want]

**WHAT I WANT**

I want you to label the `tikz in the above` code`just [![like this][2]][2] and like this [answer is labelled][1]. I want the labels to be embedded in each`arc` in the middle such that if an arc is repositioned, the label will follow automatically. [image: An image sample of what I want].

Comment: is this what you want? `\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|-|] (-30:4) arc(-30:110:4) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_1$};
\draw[|-|] (50:2) arc(50:180:2) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_2$};
\draw[|-|] (150:3) arc(150:380:3) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Yes, if it is better refined. I like it as it is written step by step.

Comment: You should make a guess for self-explained. This figure is quite simple to be written step by step. I recommend PGF manual as a TikZ's full dictionary for further checkings https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Your clue helps me make what I want.  It is simple enough for me to twist to my taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]` in the arc drawing. You can add a variable for the labels in the `\foreach` loop using the format `\foreach \num/\lab in {num1/lab1, ..., numn/labn}`. Also, using `Bar` arrow tips (provided by `arrows.meta` makes the ends easier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{declare function={hourstoangle(\h) = 90-(\h)*360/12;}}
        \def\dialR{3cm} % dial radius

        \foreach \num/\lab in {0/label 1, 1/label 2, 3/label 3, 4/label 4, 6/label 5, 7/label 6, 9/label 7, 10/label 8}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{\dialR+2mm+2mm*\num}
            
            \draw[Bar-Bar]
            ({hourstoangle(\num)}:\dist pt)
            arc[start angle={hourstoangle(\num)},end angle={hourstoangle(\num+3)},radius=\dist pt]node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{\lab};
        }
      
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am yet to get a way I can edit the `labels`. I like its output. Let's say I want to write `strings` with lexical meanings as the labels, how do I edit that.

Comment: As always: just replace `node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{\num}; ` by `node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{WHATEVER YOU WANT};` ...

Comment: @DanielJames: I edited my response. Is that what you want?

Comment: Just in case I didn't answer exactly the same thing in his previous question...